# I can't find an attribute that I used to work with in Python

Tags: python, security, cve

Did the `cpe` attribute of the object `CVE` from the nvdlib in Python get removed? I wrote code weeks ago to get the `cpe` assigned to a `cve` and it worked, now I get an error mentioning that the `cpe` attribute doesn't exist.

Here is my function:

```
def FindCpeName(CVE):
    try:
        for j in CVE.cpe:
            A = vars(j)    # make a dictionary
            cpeName = A['criteria'] #find cpe

            print(cpeName)
    except:
        print("no cpe is attached to this CVE, the vulnerability status is : ", CVE.vulnStatus)

for cve in cve_list:
    FindCpeName(cve)
```

Did the attribute get removed? How to extract the `cpe` in a similar way like the code used to do?

Comment: https://github.com/cve-search/PyCVESearch - try cpe22 or cpe23 instead